# How to disable creating an ‘.idea’ folder in Rubymine?

Tags: ruby, ide, rubymine

How to disable creating an '.idea' folder in Rubymine? It creates that folder after opening every single file and if I delete the folder, works just the same as if I don't. TIA

Comment: What is the problem with the .idea folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can (or should) disable the creation of the folder, the same as with the `nbproject` folder created by NetBeans (they probably serve similar purposes) and for that matter any `.svn` or other source control-related folders. That things still work may just mean that you haven't yet hit the place where it's going to get broken (or maybe RubyMine will just create the fodler again if you've deleted it and it needs it?).

And why would you want to? You almost certainly don't want them in source control, but that's a simple matter of setting an "ignore" property, which isn't a great hardship.

Why not [ask the RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/support/support.jsp?pr=RubyMine&ask=Problem) guys? They were pretty helpful when I had a problem.

Comment: I have some small 30 lines scripts and just want to have syntax highlighting for them. Going to ask JetBrains support

Comment: If you just need the code highlighting for 30-line script, then you probably don't need a full-blown $99 IDE for it. Try Notepad++, this is a very powerful and fast text editor.